# postgres: no op join clause for function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, postgresql-9.5

I could just do this with conditional logic, but thought I'd ask if I can do it in a single query. I want to limit the result of a query based on an array of ids, but if the array is empty, I'd like to return all rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maybe_filter(arr integer[])
  RETURNS TABLE( ... )
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
        select *
        from some_table st
        join (select distinct unnest($1) id order by 1) arr 
             on st.id = arr.id OR ...
$function$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while writing the question. Doh. But wouldn't want to deprive the world of my cleverness `<-)` so posting q/a rather than just getting back to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maybe_filter(arr integer[])
  RETURNS TABLE( ... )
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
        select *
        from some_table st
        where array_length($1,1) = 0 or st.id = any($1)
$function$;
```

Comment: `array_length($1,1)` can also be written as `cardinality($1)`

Comment: Thanks. Actually my solution doesn't seem to be working. (:  Not sure what's up yet.

Comment: Oh, maybe the cardinality thing fixed it? Before it returned 0 rows instantly, after changing array_length to cardinality it's taking a long time to run, so it's probably working....Yep, it worked. Thanks! Why would that work and not array_length = 0?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `cardinality` is the correct one to use in this case as `array_length` returns null for empty arrays and `cardinality` returns `0`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of that difference.